# Q: Getting number(integer) from Postgres and putting comma on chart

Tags: php, phplot

## What i need

Get two integer numbers from a query and put then like decimal. Example: **214566** to **214.566**

## What i've done

SQL Query

```
select to_char(numberOne,'FM999G999G999') from tableOne
```

Putting this code i get a blank chart
[image]

Changing the query for a simple result, the chart becomes visible
SQL Query

```
select numberOne from tableOne
```

[image]

**Remember, the numbers are on "Integer" type**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In line 4518 of phplot.php i've put

```
$i = 0;
$which_lab = null;
foreach($argv as $value) {
    if($i == 0) {
        $i++;
        $which_lab.= number_format($value, 2, ',','.');
    }
}
```